# Observer Pattern - Update method parameter

Tags: java

I am trying to use the properties of the object that is passed into the `notifyObservers` method, but I can't seem to find a way to access them. I can only pass in a single string, but I want more options to be passed into the observer.

This is a sample of the setup;

```
public class UpdateInfo {

          public String data;
          public int debug = 0;
}

public class RXTXComms extends Observable {

         UpdateInfo info = new UpdateInfo();

         public void sendToBoard(String s) {
                .......

                UpdateInfo.data = "test";
                UpdateInfo.debug = 1;
                stChanged();
                notifyObservers(info);
          }  
}

public class Program implements Observer {

     public void update(Observable obj, Object arg) {
            String msg = ""; // Message to display on GUI

            if (arg instanceof UpdateInfo) {
                 //Print out the message and Debug int onto GUI...but how do I access them from `arg`
        }
    }

}
```

If I make the type of `arg` to be `UpdateInfo`, then I get a compiler error that my class `Program` is not abstract....

Is this not an honest, appropriate question?

Comment: Just cast the object as UpdateInfo:  UpdateInfo UI = (UpdateInfo)arg;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast the class.

```
 UpdateInfo ui = (UpdateInfo) arg;
```

inside your `instanceof` should do the trick.

The `Observable`/`Observer` API of Java is really badly designed, don't use it. Seriously - it should not have been an abstract class, but an interface.

The observer pattern is so simple, just **implement it on your own with full type safety**. It actually does not pay off to even specify a better interfaced version of it. The various `Listener`s for example are just another instance of this pattern in Java that is much better executed: the listeners have methods with good method names and extra data, and there exists an abstract `Adapter` if there is more than one method to implement and you will often not need all of them (see e.g. `MouseAdapter`).

So **re-implement the pattern for a concrete use case**, not for the unspecified "if anything happens" case. Patterns are actually meant to be reimplemented, not abstractly inherited from a pattern library.

Comment: As a beginner, it is hard for me to figure out if it is badly implemented or not, but thanks for the heads up.